# How to define a jQuery-function which is called with an html button attribute onClick?

Tags: jquery, onclick, magento-1.9

My Problem is. I want to change required form fields before sending them. When loaded from the backend without the php number_format they show periots as decimal seperators, which I dont want but the field needs to require this. The magento classes validate the fields and I don't want to change the digits back myself or have the customer make it. Its no Problem to make the changes on(change) on(blur)or on click.

But I want the field to change on submitting the form. Here is the html:

```
<form>
  <input id="price" value="
     <?php if (isset ( $productPrice )) {
      echo number_format($productPrice, '2', ',', '.');
      } ?>" class="validate-zero-or-greater input-text validation-passed" 
     type="text"> 
</form>

<button class="button" id="actionbutton" 
 onclick="function(),checkTextarea()" type="submit" title="<?php echo $this-
 >__('Save Product') ?>">
</button>
```

and the jQuery-script with my problem in the first line:

```
 $("#price").(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
if (jQuery('#price').val().includes(','))  {

    var varwithComma = jQuery('#price').val();
    varwithoutComma = varwithComma.replace(",",".");

    jQuery('#price').val(varwithoutComma);
} else {
    console.log('No Comma');
};
```

This in the first line worked fine because of the on change event, i guess.

```
 jQuery('form').on('change', '#price', function(event){
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//bind on the submit of the form
$('#whateverMyFormSelectorIs').on('submit', function(e){
  //cancel the form submit so we can manipulate the inputs
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var $price = $('#price');
  
  //replace any comma in the price with a decimal
  //will do nothing if there are no commas
  $price.val($price.val().replace(',', '.'));
  
  //make other changes to the form
  
  //finally, submit the raw dom element
  //doing this bypasses the jQuery submit handler which should not
  //run again
  this.submit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed I do not need the if statement. I also tried the jQuery on('submit'. Somehow, this doesn't work for me. But I also don't know, what a Formselector is in your 2nd line. Do you mean the Id of the element I want to change (#price)? Should the form get an ID, which I then select or is $('form') the required entry? None of the mentioned selectors made the changes to the form. What I found out tho, is that Magento also accepts or converts numbers with comma as decimal seperator. So for me it's no problem anymore. Would still like to know, how I could make this work.

Comment: '#whateverMyFormSelectorIs' is whatever selector you want to use to target the form that will be submitted, be it the form id, or a class only on that form, or if it's the only form on the page just the tagName.

Comment: Ah ok, I just used the `jQuery('form')` as selector. So I can rule out that mistake. Also your last line didn't make it work. Thank you anyways. At least I know it's a more complex problem with Magento and the whole php-template structure. Maybe there is something happening on the submit event, that prevents the code to run properly.